# Git - Get only the new words from a commit compared to master commit/previous commit

Tags: git, diff, git-diff

How to get only the new text added to git commit (compared to previous commit or to master). For example, lets say I have text file from a previous commit, with the following content:

```
file 1:
-----------
hello my first name is john
```

And the file is edited and pushed, to:

```
file 1:
-----------
hello my last name is doe
```

I want to be able to get only the diff words - e.g. in this example to get `last doe`, to stdout or to a text file.

What is the simplest way to do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ask git to compare words instead of lines with `git diff HASH --word-diff`:

```
$ git diff HEAD^ --word-diff
diff --git a/file.txt b/file.txt
index 244f97f..ad2517e 100644
--- a/file.txt
+++ b/file.txt
@@ -1 +1 @@
hello my [-first-]{+last+} name is [-john-]{+doe+}
```

Feed output to `grep`/`sed`/`awk` to extract actual words surrounded with `{+` and `+}`. I did this with `grep -oP`, where `-P` enables perl-style regexes and `-o` displays only found parts instead of full line:

```
$ git diff HEAD^ --word-diff |grep -oP '(?<=(\{\+)).+?(?=(\+\}))'
last
doe
```

Regex breakdown:

- `(?<=(\{\+))` positive look-behind for `{+`, so these symbols are required for match, but not included into it
- `.+?` lazy search for all symbols. Without laziness will greedily include everything between the very first and very last brackets: `last+} name is [-john-]{+doe`
- `(?=(\+\}))` positive look-ahead for `+}`, similar to look-behind

Note: output won't properly include `+}` and any following text, if these symbols are actually part of your changes.